# Loop thorough **variable in C

Tags: c, pointers, 2d

I have a pointer of pointers, and I want a loop to go thorough them and store its value into something else. Is there any way to do that?

e.g:

```
char **variable;
```

Now I want to read that into another variable:

```
char **variable2
```

i thought of doing something like this:

```
for(i = 0;i <LENGTH_OF_VARIABLE-1;i++){
      variable2[i] = variable[i+1]
}
```

But that is not possible in c, right?

Now you might ask why not variable2 = variable? well variable2 should store only parts of the variable, not all of them.
EDIT: Variable's size is not known, and its dynamic(read from the command line). AND no it doesn't contain '\0' at the end. Cause its processed to remove such a character and then passed to a function that I am implementing.

Comment: This is definitely possible, but you aren't doing it correctly.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner the problem is i don't know the length of VARIABLE to start with.

Comment: You could loop through once to get the length, and loop another time to do the operation. Probably not ideal, but it's something.

Comment: I'll need to know how many elements there are. If there is no mark (like `\0`), the explicit number of elements should be passed as an argument too.

Comment: Be a little more specific - you have a previously allocated two dimensional array (array of arrays) of chars and want to make a deep copy of the array? You have to know the length of both the array of arrays and of all the arrays of chars in order to do that. Where exactly does your "variable" come from?

Comment: @Ips the program reads the input from command line and stores it in a char **INPUT variable. That is processed by a function, that removes spaces and the '\0' from the end. It then returns it as char **variable. Now I am not allowed to change anything in that function.

Comment: If this function neither tells you how many elements there are in its return array nor provides a special terminating value at the end you need to go back to whoever provided it and get one of those things. You can't iterate over a degenerate array without an end marker or known size.

Comment: In C, you don't have any information stored with the array or the pointer variable. You either have to know the length of the array, or it's end has to be marked with a special value (in case of strings, the value \0 is used). Otherwise, you just can't find the end of the array and when you try to iterate over it, you get out of its bounds and probably end up crashing on segmentation fault.

Comment: @Ips i am getting segmentation fault actually.

Comment: If you're removing the '\0', maybe you shouldn't? Or add one in at the end when you've finished getting the characters, so you know where your array ends. Otherwise you need to explicitly count the characters while they're being added to whatever memory. Doesn't make sense to not null terminate the array imo.

Comment: The interface described in the question is so completely broken that I suspect that that is not all there is to it. Perhaps the same function that removed the '\0' from each string also allocated an array of integers giving the length of each string, and somehow made a pointer to that array available; or perhaps it provides some other way of knowing the length of each string. Or perhaps it's a thoughtless mistake, but if you ask the designer of this interface how one can copy the first string without a segfault, they can either explain it or they will see their own error.

Comment: the question is unclear; the value of `variable` is a pointer to a `char *`; however you seem to be interchanging that with the value of the things being pointed to (which you haven't described well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already putting anything to your **variable, does that mean that you have allocated memory correctly? 
 I think it will better for you to revise and understand how simple one dimensional array works, after understanding that, move to double arrays. Then take a look how pointers work and learn how to allocate memory. After understanding this steps i have mentioned above, take a look at double pointers and allocation of memory in case of double pointers.
[here you go.](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/append-c.html)